# Better word for the 'keyboard-focus' tag

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, retagging

[Someone once created](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2861/drawbacks-of-auto-focusing-on-a-web-pages-text-field-javascript) the [keyboard-focus](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-focus) tag and I've reused it on [my recent question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5755/auto-focus-on-the-first-form-field-done-right) mainly because it already existed.

But I think the wording is a bit off, as the focus is not so much related to the keyboard as input device. I think [auto-focus](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auto-focus) or just [focus](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/focus) is better. Do you agree? Or is there something better?

Second, how to change it? I could retag these questions, but I was wondering if that is the best to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I say go ahead and retag to [focus](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/focus). We don't have enough questions to justify more granular tags.