# Should the "focus" tag be disambiguated?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, retagging

In the past, [focus](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/focus) was retagged from "keyboard-focus". See: [Better word for the 'keyboard-focus' tag](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253/better-word-for-the-keyboard-focus-tag).

I noticed some people using the "focus" tag, however, in a different way, such as visual or mental attention (which might be better tagged [user-attention](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-attention). This being a UX sight, with numerous people having a psych background, this is not surprising.

Should we disambiguate this tag? (It has only 20 questions.)

Answer (score 7):

One possible change could be to change **focus** to **input-focus**. This seems to make some sense, since it had originally been **keyboard-focus** in the first place. Input-focus provides greater scope than keyboard-focus, but limits the application of the tag closer to what it was intended.

Comment: Sounds good to me. I've already made Focus and Input Focus synonyms (with Input Focus as the "master") and retagged or untagged the few questions that weren't about input focus.

Comment: Nice suggestion.  I like the clarity of it.